# Problem with a long jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am running in to a strange problem with a long jQuery accordion.  Towards the top of the page, everything works great.  As soon as the page needs to scroll things start acting goofy.  The accordion tabs near the bottom of the page open just fine, but the page automatically jumps to the top when it does to forcing you to scroll back down to see the drop down?

Here is an example:
http://staging.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-xe-frequently-asked-questions

Hope I explained this ok.

Comment: I think he meant: http://embarcadero.com/products/delphi/frequently-asked-questions Maybe?

Comment: Hmm... don't see an accordion there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see your page but most likely error = you didn't add `return false()` (or `e.preventDefault();` at the end of your javascript code attached to `click` event